# iPad buyer's regret

Tags: apple-store, ipad

If someone is amazed by the **new iPad** that Apple [announced](http://www.macworld.com/article/165632/2012/03/live_update_apple_march_7_press_event.html) today, but recently bought an iPad 2 from an Apple Store, is it too late? Could that person return the previous iPad purchase in order to be able to buy the latest and greatest? What options are available for someone with buyers' remorse?

Comment: Other options include selling the iPad. Some options include Amazon, Gazelle, Craigslist, eBay, etc. Also, you could just take it as a loss and move on. New equipment will always be released, and if you have buyers remorse easily, Apple products may not be the best solution :)

Comment: A tip: next time you're thinking of buying an Apple product, check the MacRumors.com Buyer's Guide. For each product it indicates whether an update is expected soon. It's based on Apple's typical update cycles and recent rumors: http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/

Comment: @Rinzwind Good advice to anyone shopping for an Apple product.

Comment: @dpollitt I think that Apple products are very predictable in terms of when new model will be out (more or less) which is usually 1 per year. With other manufacturer's you've got bigger problem where they release 15+ products of same type all year long :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The general rule is [14 days to return things](http://store.apple.com/us/help/returns_refund), but I would just go in and let someone there know your concerns. Also, there often are price reductions which would make your recent purchase less costly if that was something you preferred to have.

Comment: Apple Store employees often bend the rules if treated nicely.  I've heard of numerous cases of that 14-day return period being extended to over a month, and have had similar good experiences myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are past the 14 day Apple return policy you can try asking your credit card company. Some, like American Express, will allow you to return merchandise for a longer period.